# I got a problem when I try to Scrape Wholefood product data with Python

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to scrape the price list for beef from the whole food website and I don't know why the output is [{'price': None}]. I want to get this output:[{'price': '$18.73'}]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://wildforkfoods.com/products/usda-choice-black-angus-beef-thick-ribeye-steak?variant=8056461918244'

headers = {
  'authority': 'p.yotpo.com',
  'accept': 'image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8',
  'accept-language': 'en,zh-CN;q=0.9,zh;q=0.8,ja-CN;q=0.7,ja;q=0.6',
  'cookie': 'pixel=051f2bf3-4b41-4f05-4f39-58fe53c3574f; pixel=051f2bf3-4b41-4f05-4f39-58fe53c3574f',
  'referer': 'https://wildforkfoods.com/',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="110", "Not A(Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="110"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'image',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'no-cors',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,'html.parser')
l=[]
obj={}
try:
    obj["price"] = soup.find("span",{"itemprop":"price"}).text.replace("Now ","")
except:
    obj["price"]=None
try:
    obj["name"] = soup.find("h1",{"itemprop":"name"}).text
except:
    obj["name"]=None
try:
    obj["rating"] = soup.find("span",{"class":"rating-number"}).text.replace("(","").replace(")","")
except:
    obj["rating"]=None
    
    l.append(obj)
print(l)
```

I want to get this output:[{'price': '$18.73'}], but my output is always {'price': None}]. I want to know what's wrong with my code.

Comment: The string "itemprop" does not exist in their page.  What are you looking for here?

Comment: Is it gives *name* and *rating* ?

Comment: use selenium. rating and price is generated by javascript. It would be hard with beautifullsoup. You should use selenium

Answer (score 0):

The selector you are using for fetching the price (`"itemprop":"price"`) does not exist in the html content.

When you are using that selector it is returning `None` and when you call the `text` attribute of the returned value (`None` in this case), the code throws error and code in `except` clause runs. ie, `obj["price"]=None`

That is why you are getting None in the final output.

You can use this CSS selector or XPath to get the span element.

**Selector:**
`#ProductForm > div.product-info__packaging-wrapper > div.product-info__pricing.product-info__pricing--left-aligned > div > span.pricing__values > span.price.price--bold.price--final > span.price__value`

**XPATH:**
`//*[@id="ProductForm"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span[2]/span[2]/span[3]`

**NOTE**: Using Broad Exception (`except:`) is not a good idea. It would make it difficult to debug code, like in this case. Always use the Error class after `except` to handle it properly.

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` this is the error your code throws when fetching the price. Just use `AttributeError` to capture the error the `except` clause.